# Rails 3. How to perform a save action on all records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model called shipments. I added some columns to the shipments table and there are some columns that are supposed to be calculated before save. So now I have to edit every record and hit update in order for the new columns to calculate and add the data.

So is there a way to perform a global save on all shipment records so the data can be added?

```
before_save :default_values
  def default_values
    self.volume = 1 unless self.volume
    self.kilograms = 1 unless self.kilograms
    self.status = "Open" if self.status.blank?
      if self.mode == "Air"
        self.estimated_transit_time = self.etd_origin + 7.days
        self.eta_place_of_delivery = self.etd_origin + 7.days
      else
        self.estimated_transit_time = self.etd_origin + (Place.find_by_city(self.place_of_loading).transit_time).days
        self.eta_place_of_delivery = self.etd_origin + (self.estimated_transit_time).days
      end
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a method like this:

```
def self.save_all
    Shipment.all.each { |shipment| shipment.save! }
end
```

Then just call:

```
Shipment.save_all
```

Comment: I get `SystemStackError (stack level too deep):` but if I run `Shipment.all.each {|shipment| shipment.save!}` in the console it works. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 51):

One liner:

```
Shipment.find_each(&:save)
```

Comment: All those solutions make n calls to database. It would be more interesting to make only 1 call like `update_all` does for collection update.

Answer (score 19):

Load your data by batch. **Never** load all at once

```
Shipment.find_each(:batch_size => 1000) do |shipment|
  shipment.save!
end
```

Then when you have to calculate some fields after a migration or something else. Simply **add this job to your migration**.

Comment: Care to share the reason to use batches rather than Model.all.each {|mdl| mld.save!} ?

Comment: @affinities23 Of course! Model.all will load all records at once. This will work just fine if you have a small amount of records, but will get slower and slower and eventually break if all the records can't fit in memory at the same time. find_each will loads by batch (No more than 1000 records loaded in memory in my example) and this will prevent the problem I just described.